# How to handle optional keys in JSON response with Java

Tags: java, json

```
"app":{  
  "icon":{  
     "icon":"TOP_RATED"
  },
  "message":{  
     "_type":"TextSpan",
     "text":"Top Rated"
  }
}
```

I keep seeing the following code in one of the projects that I have inherited. The JSON response above is parsed as follows

```
// itemObject has the entire json response
// appObject is a POJO with icon, type fields
String icon= JsonPath.with(itemObject).getAsString("icon/icon");
appObject.setIcon(icon);

String type = "";
try {
  type = JsonPath.with(itemObject).getAsString("message/_type");
catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // do nothing if type is not found in response
} finally {
    // set type to empty string if it's not found
    appObject.setType(type);
}
```

In the scenario, when _type doesn't exist for a specific app, would it be best to surround it with a try/catch block as shown above? It just seems wrong to use try/catch/finally block to process business logic instead of error handling. What is a better way to do the same and can Java 8 Optional help with this?

Comment: Though not really an answer to your question, I'd advise using jackson for json (de)serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the `org.json` package simple and straightforward. It is found [here](http://json.org/java/). The `org.json.JSONObject` class, for example, contains the `public boolean has(String key)` method, which is used to check if a certain key exists.

> Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

You can check this way where 'HAS' - Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

```
     if (json.has("status")) {
        String status = json.getString("status"));
     }
     if (json.has("club")) {
        String club = json.getString("club"));
     }
```

> You can also check using 'isNull' - Returns true if this object has no
>   mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.

```
 if (!json.isNull("club"))
     String club = json.getString("club"));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)